# Select elements for javascript by selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select this one with jquery:
`.single-product > .product-buybox-big > .col-sm-6`

You can find this on e.g. this page: [click me](https://radlvoo.de/produkt/bergamont-e-horizon-7-0-lady-lady-2017-rh-groesse-44/).

`.single-product` is on the body class. The `.product-buybox-big` can be found in `#wrapper-fluid > #main > .container > .col-sm-9 > #content` and the `.col-sm-6` element below the row in the `.product-buybox-big`.

Now here is what I have to deal with. On each product site the content is different. But I also know that on each product site there are the three classes mentioned above: `.single-product`, `.product-buybox-big` & `.col-sm-6`. How can I select them for javascript like that?

My jQuery always gets null back for this one:

```
var x = document.querySelector("single-product > product-buybox-big > col-sm-6");
```

Would be very greatful for help!
Kind regards

Comment: You are missing class selector `.`

Comment: post your html code

Comment: If you use JQuery use the `$(..selector..)` function instead to select the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JQuery, so you can use the useful [`JQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) also known as [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) function that will enable you to select an element as you would with CSS. The following code works on your page.

```
document.querySelector(".single-product .product-buybox-big .col-sm-6");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. you are missing "." selector
2. "product-buybox-big" and "col-sm-6" is not a straight child of single-product
3. you can use document.querySelector(".single-product .product-buybox-big  .col-sm-6");

Answer (score -1):

Use the JQuery's `$()` select function.

Select your element with `$('.single-product.product-buybox-big.col-sm-6')`

But if you have something like that:

```
<element class="a">
  <element class="b c">
  </element>
</element>
```

You have to put a space, like so:

```
$('.a .b.c')
```

Comment: He hasn't said if he's using jQuery, and by the looks of it, he isn't.

Comment: Yes he did, and even added the `JQuery` tag